# error configuring Jenkins to work with Git

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

im using azure devops,
while trying to run a build in jenkins im getting the following error:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://xxxx.com/_git/xxxx +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:  
stdout:   
stderr:  fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.  
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxx/_git/xxxx/': The requested URL returned error: 403   

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2102)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:853)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1224)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1213)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:637)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:509)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

if im checking  my project in jenkins - configure :

[Git SCM step error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1mVw.jpg)

*the user has all the require permissions.
*in jenkins job im using username and password method,while in the password I use the user personal access token.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the credentials used are not the correct ones, prompting Git to fall back to requesting for the username/password, which it cannot do in a Jenkins job setting environment (hence the "`user interactivity has been disabled`" error message)

Double-check the [Jenkins Credentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) "Username and password", with the PAT as password.
Once the right credentials selected, go back to the URL field, and type TAB (to get to the next field): that prompts Jenkins to try and validate the URL again.

Comment: I just tried,Still not working

Comment: @dbmoyal Is it the exact same error? If yes, the credentials are somehow for a user not allowed to access this repository.

Comment: Yes.I Just generated a new PAT and it's working.  Still don't know what happend .